# Google Login can't work

Tags: android, google-signin

I searched from web about Google Login problem after put it in Google Play Store, problem about error code 12501. All of solution is about using different SHA1 (release and debug), change build variant as release. I do all of them but didn't work. Is there anyone figured it out and can help me? Please give me some advices about it, it cost me several of days.

Comment: That's https://superuser.com/

Comment: @DaniSpringer No, it should not. The OP appears to be asking about an Android application they wrote and published -- not someone else's application that they're trying to use.